# Are read replicas heavy reading in affect masterDB?

Tags: amazon-rds, aws, aws-aurora

We have a very heavy load  in Read side with large DB tables in 2 hours per day that affect to Db so as solutions I have created read replica for it.

If application fetches large heavy data on read replica, is MasterDB affect with that havy load or it will work as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your tags, I guess its for AWS RDS Aurora. Generally, Aurora's design differs from native databases. It has a distributed storage system.

Of course, if you huge select will affect the master when you have MyISAM in place. But Aurora completely designed with InnoDB. So it won't.

Not sure whether your replica and master are in the same AZ. Its a good practice to use different AZ in Aurora.

Due to its PIOPS, your massive select load will not affect your master anyway. If you have a predictable load on a particular time, use Aurora autoscaling to share the loads between multiple read replica.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, What is I use RDS- Mysql?

Comment: I didn't get you, Are you using MySQL-RDS?

Comment: yes i am using Mysql RDS

Comment: Then you cannot use another AZ for a replica, but it has a sperate Data volume. The Disk performance will be less, but in many cases your bulk select queries are not bothering the Master until you see the replication lagg. , Please check take a look on the replication lag.

Comment: Actually my replica and master are in the same AZ.

Comment: Check the replication Lag, that is the key.